# Unexpected value 'HttpResponse' usando NGX-ADMIN con authorization

Tags: angular5

Soy nuevo en angular5 y estoy tratando de utilizar la authorization en NGX-ADMIN siguiendo la doc de https://akveo.github.io/nebular/#/docs/auth/introduction pero si bien, no me marca errores, al momento de ejecutar el ngx-admin, se queda colgando y en la consola sale el siguiente error:
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'HttpResponse' imported by the module 'CoreModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
Pongo mis fuentes:

core.module.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NbAuthModule, NbEmailPassAuthProvider } from '@nebular/auth';

import { throwIfAlreadyLoaded } from './module-import-guard';
import { DataModule } from './data/data.module';
import { AnalyticsService } from './utils/analytics.service';
import { HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { getDeepFromObject } from '../helpers/helpers';

const NB_CORE_PROVIDERS = [
  ...DataModule.forRoot().providers,
  ...NbAuthModule.forRoot({
    providers: {
      email: {
        service: NbEmailPassAuthProvider,
    config: {
      baseEndpoint: 'http://localhost/hcg/webservice/public',
      login: {
        alwaysFail: false,
        rememberMe: true,
        endpoint: '/login',
        method: 'post',
        redirect: {
          success: '/',
          failure: null,
        },
        defaultErrors: ['Login/Email combination is not correct, please try again.'],
        defaultMessages: ['You have been successfully logged in.'],
      },
      /*register: {
        alwaysFail: false,
        rememberMe: true,
        endpoint: '/api/auth/register',
        method: 'post',
        redirect: {
          success: '/',
          failure: null,
        },
        defaultErrors: ['Something went wrong, please try again.'],
        defaultMessages: ['You have been successfully registered.'],
      },
      logout: {
        alwaysFail: false,
        endpoint: '/api/auth/logout',
        method: 'delete',
        redirect: {
          success: '/',
          failure: null,
        },
        defaultErrors: ['Something went wrong, please try again.'],
        defaultMessages: ['You have been successfully logged out.'],
      },
      requestPass: {
        endpoint: '/api/auth/request-pass',
        method: 'post',
        redirect: {
          success: '/',
          failure: null,
        },
        defaultErrors: ['Something went wrong, please try again.'],
        defaultMessages: ['Reset password instructions have been sent to your email.'],
      },
      resetPass: {
        endpoint: '/api/auth/reset-pass',
        method: 'put',
        redirect: {
          success: '/',
          failure: null,
        },
        resetPasswordTokenKey: 'reset_password_token',
        defaultErrors: ['Something went wrong, please try again.'],
        defaultMessages: ['Your password has been successfully changed.'],
      },*/
      token: {
        key: 'data.token',
        getter: (module: string, res: HttpResponse<Object>) => getDeepFromObject(res.body,
          this.getConfigValue('token.key')),
      },
      errors: {
        key: 'data.errors',
        getter: (module: string, res: HttpErrorResponse) => getDeepFromObject(res.error,
          this.getConfigValue('errors.key'),
          this.getConfigValue(`${module}.defaultErrors`)),
      },
      messages: {
        key: 'data.messages',
        getter: (module: string, res: HttpResponse<Object>) => getDeepFromObject(res.body,
          this.getConfigValue('messages.key'),
          this.getConfigValue(`${module}.defaultMessages`)),
      },
     },
  },
},
  }).providers,
  AnalyticsService,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpResponse,
HttpErrorResponse
  ],
  exports: [
    NbAuthModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'CoreModule');
  }

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
return <ModuleWithProviders>{
  ngModule: CoreModule,
  providers: [
    ...NB_CORE_PROVIDERS,
  ],
};
 }
}
```

y mi app.module.ts

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Akveo. All Rights Reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for 
license information.
 */
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-
browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CoreModule } from './@core/core.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './@theme/theme.module';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

el resto de los files estan "inmaculados", osea como vienen con el ngx-admin. Me pueden dar una mano para ver que falta?. Gracias a todos por sus minutos

Comment: Estás importando HttpResponse como si fuera un módulo, elimina esa línea en la declaración de CoreModule

Comment: PabloLozano, gracias por tu comentario. Eso solucionó este inconveniente.

Comment: Ahora me dá problemas de CORS...el mensaje es el siguiente "Failed to load http://localhost/hcg/webservice/public/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."...en mi backend, uso tuupola/CORS

Comment: Eso es un problema de backend